# Why doesn't Tesla's Roadster melt in space?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, physics, heat, tesla-roadster

Tesla's Roadster is somewhere above us taking sunlight directly part of the time, then very cold on the next half of the orbit. Or when it rolls, one side gets hot, the other is cold.

Why don't the panels and other sensitive plastic things melt? Or at least degrade?

Comment: As for degradation: yes, that will probably happen over time. But not so much due to temperature as to ionising radiation.

Comment: Plastic will degrade much faster than on Earth. There is very intensive UV light not filtered by the atmosphere of the Earth. And the Sun shines 24 hours a day. Temperature cycles between hot and cold side will degrade the car too.

Comment: This is not a primary technical source, but at least a discussion of some of the materials on Roadster versus what's used in real spacecraft: https://newatlas.com/tesla-roadster-fate/53317/

Comment: Related [What is that haze on Starman's windshield?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25262/what-is-that-haze-on-starmans-windshield)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Not close enough to the Sun

The Roadster's orbit has a perihelion (closest distance to the Sun) of 0.98 AU, that is to say only very slightly closer than Earth orbit.

From [Elon Musk's Twitter](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/961083704230674438):

[image]

At Earth Orbit, the influx of energy from the Sun is about 1300 Watts per square meter. This is not far from the maximum we can have on the Earth surface. The atmosphere does dampen a bit, but at most we can get 1000 W per square meter at the equator when the Sun is at zenith.

The temperature of an object depends the flow of heat **to** it, and the flow of heat **from** it. If there is more heat coming in than is going out, the object heats up. When more heat is going out than is coming in, the object cools down. When these things are in balance, the temperature is stable.

On Earth, there are (chiefly) two things that brings heat **to** an object: the convection/conduction of the atmosphere, and radiation from the Sun. The atmosphere is a huge contributor there, at a balmy 300+ K in regions where we would even begin to consider melting plastics on an automobile. So the "baseline temperature" of an object in the Earth's atmosphere is 300 K.

Add to that another 1000 Watts per square meter from the Sun and you can have so much energy going into an object that it heats up and can eventually achieve temperatures that can melt plastic in/on a car. This is especially so if it is a coupé car, that traps warm atmosphere inside.

But in space, you do not have that atmosphere, and this was not a coupé but an open top car. Hence the baseline temperature of the car when in space is not 300+ K but 0 K.

[image]

*Note the distinct lack of an airtight enclosure around any plastic details*

So while the second contributing factor — solar radiation — is indeed 30% higher in space than it is on Earth, the lack of the first one — a warming atmosphere — completely negates that. The car will most likely freeze over time.

As for degradation: yes, that will happen over time. But not so much due to temperature as to ionising radiation. We are fortunate here on Earth to be living under a protective blanket that is the atmosphere that keeps away most of such nastiness. In space... no such luck. As the Roadster coasted around in the Van Allen belts for a few hours before being sent off for good, some people reported already seeing radiation damage on the windscreen, I assume some "yellowing" of the plastic laminate.

Comment: A warming atmosphere is not needed for an object in space to be heated by the intensive sunlight. The Moon has no atmosphere, its surface gets hot during the Moon day and cold during the night.

Comment: @Uwe Yes but for this we must consider the **convection** of heat from the ground below the surface that provides a "baseline" for the Moon's surface temperature in the same way that the atmosphere does for the Roadster on Earth. The Moon's surface temperature peeks at 127°C and dips to -173°C. So the median temperature is about -20°C, and if we ignore the Moon's hot core of about 1600-1700 K, we can assume that in this neighbourhood is where the balance point is, where the Moon's blackbody radiation balances the Sun's radiation.

Comment: Heat transfer in fluids or gases is called convection, in solids it is called conduction. In the vacuum of space heat is transfered only by radiation. There are no liquids or gases within the ground below the surface of the Moon. The hot core of the Moon might be partially liquid.

Comment: @Uwe Fair enough: **conduction** from the Moon's crust.

Comment: What does "The car will most likely freeze over time." mean? The Roadster is not currently a liquid, so... Also, re "...s to ionising radiation...", significant degradation will happen due to non-ionizing longer UV radiation from the Sun as well. The Sun has a nasty flux of UV, and much of it is non-ionizing yet really rough on polymers.

Comment: @uhoh "Freeze" as in "become a lot colder than it is now". And regarding degradation... yes, that is mentioned in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

The roadster will radiate the additional heat away.

Radiation is proportional to the fourth power of the temperature, so a slight increase in temperature massively increases the amount of outgoing heat radiation, and (with no atmosphere) there is nothing to stop it just disappearing into space.

The melting point of plastic varies a lot, but I would be surprised if the plastic in cars melted at less than 200°C. At that temperature, a back-of-the-envelope calculation would show 6 or 7 times the outgoing radiation than at room temperature, whereas the radiation coming in is only slightly more than the maximum on earth.

In addition, part of the car will be in shadow and not receiving any direct heat, but still radiating away heat that has conducted from other parts of the car.

So, in summary, the heat radiated will exceed the heat received before it gets hot enough to melt.

Comment: Would you mind posting your back of the envelope calculation? Thanks.

Comment: Room temperature = 293K, 200°C = 493K. 493^4/293^4 = 6.79. I am assuming all other components of the equation are constants. But I am not an expert on this, so I welcome any corrections, though I think the general argument is correct and I didn't mean to imply the calculation was exact (hence, the envelope).

Answer (score 3):

The Tesla will most definitely degrade significantly on this mission. It is not designed in any way shape or form for this sort of mission.

SpaceX/Musk know this, and completely admit it was just a silly thing to launch for the sake of its silliness.

Musk in the post mission press conference said he expected it to not last very long.

People are already reporting that the windshield was showing damage, before the camera shut off.

Comment: Got a link to those reports?

Comment: @MichaelK see https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25262/what-is-that-haze-on-starmans-windshield

Comment: This needs some citations.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Roaster is some 94M miles from the Sun. For contrast, Mercury is some 35M miles away from the Sun (almost 3x the distance away)
2. There's nothing close to the Tesla to retain any heat. Mercury's maximum temperature is about 800F/425C. The Roadster shouldn't get even remotely that close, and even if it did, nothing would hold the heat near to the Roadster

Comment: Space is not cold. Temperature is a quality of matter. Space is the (near) complete absence of matter. Hence space has no temperature. And while there are tiny amounts of matter in space — the [Interplanetary Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_medium) — it is not dense enough to be of significance for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The car **will** degrade (not melt),.. slowly.  As stated in other answers, the roadster won't get close enough to the Sun to cause it to melt, however, it **will** in fact decay.  Chemist Richard Sachleben states in this article from Life Science [Radiation will Tear Roadster Apart](https://www.livescience.com/61680-will-spacex-roadster-survive-in-space.html) that it will take a long time for parts like the windshield to discolor and come apart relative to any organic material in the car (leather seats, rubber tires) and will only start to do so as the plastic in the windshield starts to decay. He believes the organics will last around a year, but gives no specific guess on the glass.  He believes the car will continue to decay until all the is left is the metal frame and probably the electric motor.