# Starman and Tesla temperatures

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster, payload

As The Tesla car and Starman continue to orbit the earth, How does the paint on the car survive the extremes of temperature? As I understand it, they are both exposed to temperatures between 120C and -100C.

Comment: See these questions and the answers: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25269/why-doesnt-the-tesla-roadsters-windscreen-crack-or-break-in-space/25304#25304), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/why-doesnt-teslas-roadster-melt-in-space/24957#24957).

Comment: What do you mean by "survive"?  They're not alive.

Answer (score 4):

The car will be heated to both the extremes. The side facing the sun directly could have scorching temperatures over 130 celcius while the rear side not receiving any sun could get as cold as -173 celsius.
This will result in uneven expansion and contraction of the metallic body and the paint will undoubtedly flake of and cause serious damage to the internals.

The roadster, starman, tires, plastics, seats and other parts will be degraded by the radiations and the paint on the body will also fade for the same reason. 
Micrometeors may hit the car and dent it as well.
Though it is predicted to remain in orbit for millions of years, it will probably disintegrate due to the suns strong radiations long before that.

Comment: This all sounds very reasonable, but do you think the frame will also "disintegrate" in a million years? I have no idea myself. https://www.teslarati.com/tesla-model-3-body-structure-steel-aluminium-composition/

Comment: Maybe not the frame, unless it is some sort of carbon fibre and steel composite because it is a supercar after all.

Comment: Ya I think it will look like a dinosaur skeleton, and astro-archaeologists will have to theorize what the original body shape and color was. They may theorized that it was coldblooded and had feathers!